# Order random effects are entered into the model affects estimates

Tags: r

In a linear mixed model setting, the order I enter my variables into the model (both as random effects and as fixed effects) seemingly affects the estimates I get from the model. In an OLS setting this is not the case.

Could anybody explain why the resulting estimated fixed effects vary when I either change the order in which the fixed effects enter the model or the order of the random effects? Because I fail to see how

```
lmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + (1 + X1 + X2 | f) )
```

differs from

```
lmer(Y ~ X2 + X1 + (1 + X2 + X1 | f) )
```

A short example is presented below.

```
library(lme4)

lmer1 <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ 1 + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length +
Petal.Width  + (1 + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width  |
Species), data=iris)

lmer2 <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ 1 + Sepal.Width +
Petal.Length + Petal.Width  + (1 + Petal.Width + Sepal.Width +
Petal.Length  | Species), data=iris)

lmer3 <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ 1 +
Petal.Width + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + (1 + Petal.Width +
Sepal.Width + Petal.Length  | Species), data=iris)

fixef(lmer1)
fixef(lmer2)
fixef(lmer3)[c("(Intercept)",  "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length",  "Petal.Width")]
```

The output from these three seemingly identical models is presented below:

```
> fixef(lmer1)
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   1.6707431    0.4711415    0.7266866   -0.2240361 
> fixef(lmer2)
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   1.6707432    0.4711417    0.7266866   -0.2240366 
> fixef(lmer3)[c("(Intercept)",  "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length",  "Petal.Width")]
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   1.6707428    0.4711414    0.7266866   -0.2240358
```

Now, while the estimated fixed effects are so similar that the difference between them hardly would be of any practical importance, it still makes me wonder why it happens.

Comment: Why aren't they equivalent?

Comment: This is a known issue, check: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/449

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos Thank you for that link. So in other words it's a bug and not something inherently strange in the LMM framework?

Comment: Yes, theoretically shouldn't happen. And also in practice most often doesn't occur, but it can occur in some *pathological* cases (e.g., fitting a model that is too complex for your data). Hence, it is an indication to carefully check things...

Comment: Turns out that the order of the rows in the dataframe also is relevant for the estimates: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127479/glmer-in-r-significance-estimates-are-not-robust-to-order-of-data-frame?rq=1

Comment: Can you add the output of your code to the question so that everybody could see the difference you are referring to without needing to run your code in R?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable request to me @amoeba! I have done that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment to my original post, it turns out that this is a known bug the lme4 package; see https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/449. Hopefully this will be resolved in future releases of the the package. My thanks to Dimitris Rizopoulos for providing this information.

Furthermore, it turns out that the order of the rows in the dataset also affects the estimates in a similar way: [glmer in R: Significance estimates are not robust to order of data frame](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127479/glmer-in-r-significance-estimates-are-not-robust-to-order-of-data-frame?rq=1)

In other words, how we enter variables into lmer and in which order the rows of the dataset are placed, currently affect the estimates. Hopefully these issues can be resolved in the future as it is, in my opinion, not an attractive property for a statistical tool to have.

Comment: The answers here should not be used this way, the better way is to pst an answer yourself, citing the comment!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps also edit the answer to include your comment about row order to make this even more useful?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, @mdewey. I have edited my answer to also include that. Thank you for the suggestion.